# Unintentional override to Sidebar B module made it disappear. How to restore?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, joomla-3.5, template-override

I was in the Template section, (as a novice, in the wrong area) trying to change the appearance of a module. I clicked on Create Overrides tab, then in the third column Layouts list, clicked "sidebar B". I exited that page, clearly not knowing what I was doing, and then realized I made all sidebar B modules throughout the site disappear, and I don't know how to revert it back to what it was.

I found that replacing the config.json file with an older version restores the sidebar B modules throughout the site, however, as soon as I go back into to the Templates > Styles area all Sidebar B's throughout the site disappear again and the actual backend page appearance of the template area changes.

I am using Yootheme's "Eat" theme and just want to revert back to the default so that the sidebar B modules show up again.

Is there any way I can permanently restore without losing all of my site data? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it is better to ask this question in dedicated support forum of Yootheme http://yootheme.com/support

Answer (score 1):

Any overrides created via the template section can just be removed with the manage folders button. Deleting an override that you have done nothing to wont hurt anything.